# Kendoui: Get tab name when click on tab in kendoui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip( {
            animation:  {
                open: {
                    effects: "fadeIn"
                }
            },
  select: function(element){alert('alert select tab name');}            
        });
        });
```

hi..
i want alert tab name when i select on tab in kendo tabstrip.

Any one help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found
         select: function(element){alert( $(element.item).text())}